# How can you display the full path of a linked static library in an executable in Windows 8.1

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2013, linker

Given the following Assembly language program (add2sub1asm):

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.code
main PROC
    mov eax, 10000h
    add eax, 40000h
    sub eax, 20000h
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

assembled with the following command:
    ml /c /Fl /Zi add2sub1.asm

and linked with this command:
    link add2sub1 /subsystem:CONSOLE user32.lib kernel32.lib /debug /map /verbose

I would like to be able to determine exactly (by it's full path) which user32.lib or kernel32.lib file is included, but this information does not display on screen, in the list or map output or with dumpbin output.

What's the best way to get this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`/verbose:lib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6) to the `link.exe` commandline.

```
Searching libraries
    Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB\msvcprtd.lib:
    Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB\MSVCRTD.lib:
    Searching c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB\OLDNAMES.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\user32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\advapi32.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\uuid.lib:
    Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib\kernel32.lib:
```

Comment: I figured out that the /verbose:lib option only displays the search list when the exe doesn't exist (or when it needs to be rebuilt). The solution was to delete the exe, add the option and rerun link.